# Unable to use sendKeys() method into the paragraph tag from Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Here is an image of the page I'd like to edit:

[image]

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="taTextElement7190829193028565" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ta-bind" contenteditable="true" ta-bind="ta-bind" ng-model="html">
<h3>Problem Scenario</h3>
<p>ff-224</p>
<h3>Diagnostics</h3>
<p>
<h3>Resolution Steps</h3>
<p>
</div>
```

Now, I am using `sendKeys()` function in order to pass the value into the paragraph tag.

```
String PS_XPath = "//div[contains(@class, 'ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ta-bind')]/p[2]";
WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath(PS_XPath));
element.click();
element.sendKeys("Test");
```

But the `sendKeys()` functionality is not working.

Comment: Do you get any error? or is it just continue without doing anything?

Comment: It is just not doing anything.

Comment: Any help anyone please.

Comment: How you want to send text to `<p>` element?

Comment: You can use `sendKeys` method to enter value to input field which as I know marked with `<input>` tag or `<textarea>`...

Comment: so, in that case, how can I then pass on text value into the <p> tags please. This is the requirement that I need to fulfill. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You cannot change static text web-element (e.g. header, link, text...) with `selenium`. You should change `html` code itself

Comment: But this is not a static content as when I execute this manually, I can add some text into the paragraph runtime.

Comment: actually, in ur web page, is there option to enter ur value manually...i mean is there any textbox at your given html element???

Comment: no there is not. in the webpage, I need to enter the value for Diagnostics and Resolution Steps. Given is the screenshot of the same(found at the top of my question posted). Let me know how can i fix the same.

Comment: Any suggestion please.

Comment: @Sayom did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 6):

This cannot be done just by using plain webdriver methods. But you can do it using JavascriptExecutor.
This should work:

`JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("document.getElementsByTagName('p')[2].innerHTML = 'Sample text'");`

Where:

[2] - index of needed tag.

Sample text - replace with **YOUR** text.

Comment: Hello @Reuven Volnoboy, I have done as you have suggested, but still the problem is not solved. Here is the code that I am using.                                                                                                 String PS_XPath = "//div[contains(@class, 'ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ta-bind')]/p[2]";
WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath(PS_XPath));
element.click();
Thread.sleep(1000);
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("document.getElementsByTagName('p')[2].innerHTML = 'Test Value'");

Comment: Nothing happened? Look, those two lines are independent of your Xpath or any actions you have done before. If you know how to debug javascript in browser(for example chrome) try to execute this line: "document.getElementsByTagName('p')[2].innerHTML = 'Test Value'" 
May be simply you need to change index of <p> tag, because you didn't show us all html code. I have created page exactly like you showed us and debugged in chrome, everything was working.